# How to Extend the Volume on hyper-V

Tags: partitioning, hyper-v, virtual-disk

I want to expand a 100GB Virtual Hard disk to 200GB; so using Hyper-v settings I expanded it to 200GB. Now back to the guest OS (Windows 10), the additional space is clearly there, it says space is unallocated. So I right-click on Extend, the wizard says "Total volume 204782MB but Max available is 102400. If i enter a number higher than the max, the Next button becomes grayed out.

What i tried so far: Formated the unallocated space to NTFS, but then the Option to extend (on the left hand side volume) becomes grayed out.

What next?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those fields don't show the final size, they show the size *to be added* to the existing volume. So because you have grown the VHD by 100 GB, now you also have to select 100 GB.

Just accept the default max, click "Next", and the partition will be grown to fill the whole disk as expected.